# How do I get the value of a failed request in Dispatch?

Tags: scala, scala-dispatch

When I make a request in Dispatch, I apply the Promise and get this:

```
Left(dispatch.StatusCode: Unexpected response status: 400)
```

How do I get the actual text of the response? I'm using Solr and it still returns valuable JSON with failed HTTP requests.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you've written something like the following:

```
Http(url OK as.String)
```

The `OK` is what's providing the simple error handling you see here. You can use `>` to get the results more directly. For example, if you write this:

```
Http(url("http://google.com/") OK as.String).either()
```

You'll get the following (at the moment, at least):

```
Left(dispatch.StatusCode: Unexpected response status: 301)
```

But if you make the following small change:

```
Http(url("http://google.com/") > as.String).either()
```

You get the full body of the redirect page:

```
res1: Either[Throwable,String] = 
Right(<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" ...
```

If you want to do something fancier with the response, you can write your own `asWhatever` handler—see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13653035/334519) for a demonstration of how to get access to the headers as a map, for example.

Comment: Do you know where the documentation is maintained for the databinder website? I wouldn't mind contributing and adding in the small use cases like this.